# Python continuously updating array

Tags: python, arrays

I wrote a simple backtracking algorithm in python to solve sudoku's, and for a while had difficulty because it seemed to update an array that should not have been updated, which caused the entire program to backup.

Essentially, as part of the code, I stored an array of the initial values and then made a copy of the array so that when I was backtracking and assigning new values, I didn't change any of the numbers that were given in the original sudoku. However, in the process I somehow updated my array of initial numbers. I eventually figured out it was being caused by the line `grid=initial`, which should have set my working grid (grid) to the initial values (initial) but was only called at the start of the program. When I took that line out and manually assigned grid to the same thing as initial (via copy/paste), the program worked fine.

I've included my full code below, anybody know why that line may have been getting called again? I can't figure it out.

```
initial=[[0,0,0,0,7,0,1,4,0],
         [2,0,0,0,1,5,3,0,6],
         [0,6,1,0,3,0,0,0,8],
         [0,0,0,7,0,0,0,5,3],
         [0,0,9,0,0,0,8,0,0],
         [0,7,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
         [1,0,0,0,4,0,0,9,0],
         [9,0,6,1,0,0,0,0,2],
         [0,2,3,0,9,0,0,0,0]]

#The following line used to be grid=initial

grid=[[0,0,0,0,7,0,1,4,0],
         [2,0,0,0,1,5,3,0,6],
         [0,6,1,0,3,0,0,0,8],
         [0,0,0,7,0,0,0,5,3],
         [0,0,9,0,0,0,8,0,0],
         [0,7,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
         [1,0,0,0,4,0,0,9,0],
         [9,0,6,1,0,0,0,0,2],
         [0,2,3,0,9,0,0,0,0]]


def printBoard(grid):
    for i in range(0,8):
        print(grid[i])

def checkValidity(num,row,col):
    if num in grid[row]:
        return False


    for i in range(0,8):
        if grid[i][col]==num:
            return False


    cageRow=row//3
    cageCol=col//3
    for i in range(0,3):
        if num in grid[3*cageRow+i][3*cageCol:3*cageCol+3]:
            return False


    return True

def nextCell(row,col,backtrack):
    if backtrack==0:
        if col==8:
            row+=1
            col=0
        else:
            col+=1
    else:
        if col==0:
            row-=1
            col=8
        else:
            col-=1
    if row<0:
        print("Error: Backtracked too far.")
    return (row,col)

def findNewNumber(row,col,num,backtrack):
    for i in range(num+1,10):
        if checkValidity(i,row,col):
            return (i,0)
    return (0,1)


row=0
col=0
backtrack=0
print("Solving...")

while row<9:
    if grid[row][col]==initial[row][col] and initial[row][col]!=0:
        [row,col]=nextCell(row,col,backtrack)
    else:
        num=grid[row][col]
        grid[row][col]=99
        [num,backtrack]=findNewNumber(row,col,num,backtrack)
        grid[row][col]=num
        [row,col]=nextCell(row,col,backtrack)

print("Solved!")
printBoard(initial)
print("")
printBoard(grid)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grid = initial
id(initial) == id(grid)
>>> True
```

This doesn't set `grid` to the same values as `initial`.  It makes `grid` refer to the same object as `initial`.  What people commonly do is make a shallow copy, like this

```
grid = initial[:]
id(initial) == id(grid)
>>> False
```

This will not work in your case though.  It would create a new outer list that will hold the same interior lists.

```
id(initial[0]) == id(grid[0])
>>> True
```

What you need is a `deepcopy` to get copies of the interior lists as well.

```
import copy

grid = copy.deepcopy(initial)
```

then everything is copied

```
id(initial) == id(grid)
>>> False
id(initial[0]) == id(grid[0])
>>> False
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a similar method for copying arrays in javascript? I'm currently in the process of learning JS, and built this in python to see if the problem was with the algorithm itself or with my implementation.